# Why is the audio category of my files incomplete?

Tags: file-management, media-files, media-scanner

I have recorded some .wav files with my Samsung S7. They are located in a folder of the recoding app.

Unfortunately the audio category of the [my files (Samsung) file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.myfiles) only lists some of them. Those recorded within the last 5 days are missing.

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: What app is it? Its not helpful if we dont know, it could be app-specific.

Comment: And by "audio category" you mean inside that app, or somewhere (where?) else?

Comment: The app is Zoiper IAX SIP VOIP Softphone Lite, but I think it is a generic problem independent of the recording app. I have also added a link to the Samsung file manager.